# How can you add route to Nodejs without restarting the server?

Tags: node.js, server

I  am searching for a way to create a "Forgot password" page for my users.

It must have the following features:

1. URLs must be unique and random for individual user. I decided to use a hash function for this.
2. URLs must expire after users finish obtaining a new password or after a time-out period has ended.
3. Web-server cannot be changed by this operation.

Webserver : `Node.js 5.2.0`
Module : `Expressjs 4.13.3`

In my understanding, `Node.js` needs to restart itself every time when I add a new/remove `route`. Currently, my colleague uses `nodemon`. Although it is a good application, it is not ideal for a "forgot password" page due to the fact that it restarts the web-server each time it runs.

**Question:**

1. What is the best technique for this scenario?
2. What is a specific keyword for this question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add routes using path parameters in Node (I assume you're using Express.js, but if you clarify I can modify this answer).

In this case you would register a route like this:

```
/api/v1/user/forgotPasswordEndpoint/:unique_hash
```

This would match things such as

```
/api/v1/user/forgotPasswordEndpoint/12345
```

You can access `12345` through `req.params.unique_hash`. This lets you treat that endpoint differently based on the hash, and grants you access to the hash in your code so you can do something with it.

Comment: Yes. I am using `Express`.

Comment: Thank you. It has to use with database to store the `:unique_hash`. I thought it can be done with database.

Answer (score 1):

Node will only need to be restarted after you change the actual *code* for your Forgot Password page, *not* every time someone clicks on Forgot Password.  "Adding a route" means adding the code in your app that handles that `forgot_password` link.

Comment: I read you post, but not to be able to understand untill zackehh reply. Thank you.